# I tried to create an overlay with Javascript but the overlay don't show up

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to create an overlay but when I click on the button the overlay don't show up.

In the console log the error '**overlay.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null**' appears. I already tried by myself to solve this problem, I'm just a beginner.. I hope someone can solve the problem for me. Thanks for the effort!

**HTML**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

<link
        href="style.css" media="screen,projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>



<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
</head>

<body>

<div id="nav" class="overlay">

    <button id="afsluiten" href="#" class="close">Afsluiten</button>

    <div class="overlay__content">

        <a href="">Home</a>
        <a href="">Profile</a>
        <a href="">Images</a>
        <a href="">About</a>
        <a href="">Product</a>

    </div>

</div>

<button id="open" href="#" class=open"">Open Overlay</button>

<script src="overlay.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
    body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.overlay{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background: limegreen;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 5;
}

.overlay__content{

  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a{

  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.overlay .close{

  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var open = document.querySelector('.open');
var close = document.querySelector('.close');

open.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    openOverlay();
}, false);

function openOverlay() {

    document.querySelector('.nav').style.width = "100%";
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelector` returns an _array_ of elements, not a _single_ element. You also have your quotes messed up on your class: `class=open""`

Comment: `document.querySelector` returns a single element. It's `document.querySelectorAll` that returns an array (actually a NodeList).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line `<button id="open" href="#" class=open"">Open Overlay</button>` has a typo on the class name

`<button id="open" href="#" class="open">Open Overlay</button>`

Comment: Omg, that was really stupid of me that I am ashamed.. Sorry.. Thank you very much for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

The DOM hasn't been loaded yet. You need to put in the handler to the load event